# Error while building Apache Ignite Source

Tags: java, node.js, ignite

I have downloaded the source of **apache-ignite-2.76** and trying build the project with following command

`mvn clean package -DskipTests`

But it is throwing following error:-

```
 Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project ignite-tools: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /home/blazehub/dev-install/apache-ignite-2.7.6-src/modules/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/tools/javadoc/IgniteLinkTaglet.java:[21,29] package com.sun.tools.doclets does not exist
[ERROR] /home/blazehub/dev-install/apache-ignite-2.7.6-src/modules/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/tools/javadoc/IgniteLinkTaglet.java:[30,42] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class Taglet
[ERROR] /home/blazehub/dev-install/apache-ignite-2.7.6-src/modules/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/tools/javadoc/IgniteLinkTaglet.java:[37,5] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /home/blazehub/dev-install/apache-ignite-2.7.6-src/modules/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/tools/javadoc/IgniteLinkTaglet.java:[44,5] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /home/blazehub/dev-install/apache-ignite-2.7.6-src/modules/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/tools/javadoc/IgniteLinkTaglet.java:[51,5] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /home/blazehub/dev-install/apache-ignite-2.7.6-src/modules/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/tools/javadoc/IgniteLinkTaglet.java:[58,5] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /home/blazehub/dev-install/apache-ignite-2.7.6-src/modules/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/tools/javadoc/IgniteLinkTaglet.java:[65,5] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /home/blazehub/dev-install/apache-ignite-2.7.6-src/modules/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/tools/javadoc/IgniteLinkTaglet.java:[72,5] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /home/blazehub/dev-install/apache-ignite-2.7.6-src/modules/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/tools/javadoc/IgniteLinkTaglet.java:[79,5] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /home/blazehub/dev-install/apache-ignite-2.7.6-src/modules/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/tools/javadoc/IgniteLinkTaglet.java:[88,5] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /home/blazehub/dev-install/apache-ignite-2.7.6-src/modules/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/tools/javadoc/IgniteLinkTaglet.java:[100,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Taglet
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ignite.tools.javadoc.IgniteLinkTaglet
[ERROR] /home/blazehub/dev-install/apache-ignite-2.7.6-src/modules/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/tools/javadoc/IgniteLinkTaglet.java:[119,5] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /home/blazehub/dev-install/apache-ignite-2.7.6-src/modules/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/tools/javadoc/IgniteLinkTaglet.java:[161,5] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

Comment: Hi, which java version do you use?

Comment: openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Apache Ignite 2.7.x will only build with Java 8. You can use binary builds with Java 11, however.